# Lesson in an induction problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm trying to do this problem but I'm having a basic misunderstanding that just needs some clarification.

Consider the proposition that $P(n) = n^2 + 5n + 1$ is even.

Prove $P(k) \to P(k+1)$ $\forall k \in \mathbb N$.

For which values is this actually true?

What is the moral here?

This problem is meant to tell you a moral problem of induction. I'm aware that $P(n)$ is odd for all integers (I think), so I can't think of where to start on this. This is in regard to induction specifically even if the problem doesn't implicitly state it.

Comment: The moral here is that you canmot forget the base cases when doing induction proofs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing the base case before the inductive step. It can be shown that $n=k+1$ follows from $n=k$ using just the inductive step, however that does not imply that the proposition is true.

---

Here I demonstrate this:

Assume true for $n=k$ where $p\in \mathbb{Z}$:
$$k^2+5k+1=2p$$
For $n=k+1$:
$$(k+1)^2+5(k+1)+1=k^2+2k+1+5k+5+1=(k^2+5k+1)+2k+6$$
Substituting gives:
$$2p+2k+6$$
Hence, this implies that $n=k+1$ follows from $n=k$.

---

However, note that when we do the base case, $n=1$, we see that this proposition is not true:
$$1^2+5+1=7$$

Answer (score 1):

While you can prove the step that $P(k) \rightarrow P(k+1)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, it does *not* follow that "$n^2+5n+1$ is even" for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

In other words, the moral is to *never* forget to prove the base case for induction, for otherwise you might be proving things that are just not true.

Here is a simpler example:

Suppose I want to use induction to prove $P(n): n > n + 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

OK, so take arbitrary $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and suppose (inductive hypothesis) that $k > k + 1$. Well, then obviously $k + 1 > (k + 1) + 1$, and so the inductive step is proven. So there!

But wait! Clearly $n > n + 1$ is *not* true!  What happened? I forgot the base case!

Comment: This was so apparent that I didn't recognize it was a problem haha, thank you

Comment: @HowardP Right! :)  But there will be (less obvious!) cases where you are so focused on the step that you forget the base case ... and with the wrong claim going in, the inductive step works out nicely, but the wrong result gets 'proven'. This has happened to me on more than one occasion! So it's good to get this reminder moral once and a while.